# Regular variation and linearity

Tags: limits, functions

So the definition of regular variation is the following:

A regularly varyng function $L: (0,+ \infty) \rightarrow (0,+ \infty)$ has the following property:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{L(t x)}{L(x)} = g(t)
\end{equation}

I am under the impression that if $g(t)=t$. This implies that $L(x)$ is eventually linear in $x$ if $x$ is large enough. True/false?

Comment: Consider $L(x) = x + \frac 1 {x}$.

Comment: @nicomezi It looks like it is true for this function. Is it true generaly?

Comment: Well $L$ gets closer and closer to a linear function but it will never be.

Comment: @nicomezi Hm is there a formal way to say that?

Comment: The derivative is never a constant for $x >1$.

Comment: @nicomezi Hm but that doesn't say that as x increases the linear approximation becomes better or something like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100370/discussion-between-dio-and-nicomezi).

Comment: @Dio: what do you mean by being linear eventually? The function $R(x)=x\log x$ is of regular variation with exponent $1$ ($g(t)=t$). More general, any function of the form $\phi(x)=x c(x)\exp\Big(\int^x_1\frac{\varepsilon(s)}{s}\,dy\Big)$ with $c(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty} c$, $c>0$, and $\varepsilon(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}0$ is of regular variation with exponent $1$. However, $\phi(x)$ is not asymptotic to a linear function in general.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition:
$$L(x)-L(a x) = L(x) - f(a)L(x) = L(x)(1-f(a)) $$
$$ L(y)-L(b y) = L(y) - f(b)L(y) = L(y)(1-f(b)) $$
    Linearity  implies:
$$ x-ax = y-yb $$
$$ \rightarrow y = x \frac{(1-a)}{(1-b)} $$
So:
$$ \rightarrow L\left(x \frac{1-a}{1-b}\right)[1-f(b)] $$
$$ \rightarrow f\left( \frac{1-a}{1-b}\right)L(x)[1-f(b)] $$
    L is linear in x if
$$L(x)f\left(\frac{1-a}{1-b}\right)(1-f(b)) = L(x)(1-f(a))$$ 
$$f\left(\frac{1-a}{1-b} \right) = \frac{1-f(a)}{1-f(b)} $$
$$\left(\frac{1-a}{1-b} \right)^i = \frac{1-a^i}{1-b^i} $$

Where that last part follows from the definition of slowly varying functions: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function#CITEREFBinghamGoldieTeugels1987

Since $i=1$ this is verified